# ASP.NET MVC RegularExpression Attribute Not Working with Parenthesis (literal)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

**Here's my sample regex in c#.**

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|\x28[0-9]{3,5}\x29$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Format. xxxx-xxxx or xxxx-xxxx (xxxxx)")]
```

**I've already tried this two regex but still not working.**

- ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|\([0-9]{3,5}\)$
- ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|\x28[0-9]{3,5}\x29$

**Here's the html output**

data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|\x28[0-9]{3,5}\x29$"

**Desired Output Sample**

- 1234-1234
- 1234-1234 (123)
- 1111-1111 (11111)
- ...

I'm testing the regex here at https://regex101.com/ and works as expected but not in my c# code.

**Validation still triggers even the input is valid**

[image]

Comment: @JakubRusilko what do you mean by sample code? c# code, razor code or the html part?

Comment: ignore my previous comment - I removed it. Didn't notice you are using it in the attribute. Try my answer below.

Comment: i edited my question, because stackoverflow also escaped the backlash i put in my question.

Comment: Ok, so what do you exactly mean, by the "code not working"?

Comment: the validation triggers even the input is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this regex does match, but it is not a FULL match - only partial. Use this:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}( \([0-9]{3,5}\))?$
```

Your version was an alternative: either the first part OR the second part. My version is: always the first part AND MAYBE the second part (if present).

Comment: Yes, but `( \([0-9]{3,5}\))*` must probably be `( \([0-9]{3,5}\))?`, i.e. allow it one or zero times.

Comment: You are right, Wiktor. My bad. Fixed the answer, thanks.

Comment: @JakubRusilko this is working. Thanks. Also Wiktor thank you.